# Textmate: HTML syntax: embedded in PHP single and double quotes

Tags: php, html, syntax, scope, textmate

Is there anyway to highlight HTML embedded in PHP single and double quotes — which has no scope defined, within Textmate?

Example:

`printf( 'This is some <strong>Text</strong>', 'foobar' );`

Everything within the single quotes belong to the same scope. Its annoying. Has anyone tried to fix this somehow? I'd rather not alter the language files (without guidance), im not fluent in regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, i found out how to do it. After reading on how scopes work in Textmate. I opened up the PHP languages panel under the Bundle Editor and pasted an include of the following scope name into the `string-single-quoted` scope:

`text.html.basic`

Heres the include:

`{   include = 'text.html.basic'; },`

and heres how the entire `string-single-quoted` section looks like now:

```
string-single-quoted = {
        name = 'string.quoted.single.php';
        contentName = 'meta.string-contents.quoted.single.php';
        begin = "'";
        end = "'";
        beginCaptures = { 0 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.string.begin.php'; }; };
        endCaptures = { 0 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.string.end.php'; }; };
        patterns = (
            {   include = 'text.html.basic'; },
            {   name = 'constant.character.escape.php';
                match = '\\[\\'']';
            },
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to do some rather complicated editing of the scope definitions for HTML in order to get this to work as you describe. PHP files are HTML files by default in TextMate, so you're looking to define a scope where you have an HTML file with embedded PHP with strings that might be HTML. Not every string in PHP is going to be HTML, so you'd need to figure out a way to differentiate non-HTML strings from HTML strings, and if you're not fluent with regular expressions, it would probably take quite a bit of research and trial and error to get it right.

As an alternative, if you're actually using `printf` rather than simply using it as a generic example, consider using the function to format only what you need formatted and doing something like this.

```
<?php
$var = sprintf( '%d', $num );
?>
Here's the <strong><?php echo $var; ?></strong>.
```

Comment: thanks but after "trial and error" (alot of it) i actually got it to work.

Comment: Very cool. I'll try integrating it into my own TM environment. :)

Comment: Yea i cant believe people haven't though of documenting/sharing it. i would really like to love Textmate, but customizing it is harder (and mind boggling at times) than much apps right now. I'm currently using Espresso.app, which has a much more natural feel to it than Textmate, but honestly you cant beat the features of Textmate. Glad you found it useful. Though im not sure if this is the proper way to add support for additional syntax within another.

Comment: Well, ironically, I'm actually going through vim tutorials now in anticipation of giving up on TextMate. :(

Comment: oh by the way, i found a little tiny problem. If an HTML tag doesn't have an ending angle bracket (i.e '<div' vs. '<div>' ) then it ruins everything after the single quotes. Im trying to figure out how to make sure the single quotes act like a "cut-off" point